# bs4 парсинг ссылок

Tags: python, парсер, bs4

Начал изучение библиотеки bs4. Подскажите пожалуйста , как правильно извлечь ссылки из кода ниже.
Имеется такой код :

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

link = ('https://coinmarketcap.com/new/')
parse = requests.get(link).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(parse, 'lxml')
price = soup.find_all('a', {"class": "cmc-link"})


ticker_link = []

for i in price:
    ticker_price.append(i.get('href'))
```

Ссылки хотел извлечь для того, чтобы по линку перейти на тикер и после спарсить от туда цену. Не получается, у меня с текущей страницы вырвать цену из span, поэтому хотел попробовать через парс ссылок , а после переход на страницу , где можно попробовать спарсить саму цену.

спасибо!
Или подскажите , как можно было в этом коде , сразу спарсить цену без перехода по линку тикера.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

link = ('https://coinmarketcap.com/new/')
parse = requests.get(link).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(parse, 'lxml')
for i in soup.findAll('tr')[1:]:
    ii = [x.text for x in i.findAll('td')[2:8]]
    tt = ii[0]
    pr = ii[1]
    print(tt)
    print(pr)

Dystopia1DYST
$0.1353
MetaCars2MTC
$0.000001872
....
4MOVE294MOVE
$0.004826
VRYNT30VRYNT
$0.003241
```

можно еще через pandas

```
import pandas

pandas.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
aa = pandas.read_html('https://coinmarketcap.com/new/')
print(aa)
```

Comment: спасибо большое , то что вы показали , это конечно супер , я пока что имеющий совсем мало опыта в пайтоне , пытаюсь обходить все гораздо сложными путями 'как оказывается в итоге' =) Ну на таких советах , как ваш, учусь гораздо быстрее и правильнее.

Comment: "Практика, практика, и еще раз практика" В. И. Ленин. :) Поэтому я нахожусь на данном рессурсе.